# How to associate a Deployment/Pod to a non-default service account by default

Tags: kubernetes, service-accounts, k8s-serviceaccount

When we do not specify any service account in the deployment/pod manifests, it gets associated with the "default" service account in the corresponding namespace.

My question is, can this behavior be changed so that by default, the deployment/pod gets associated with a custom service account in the pods namespace (without needing to specify the custom service account in each deployment/pod manifests)?

Any links to documentation on achieving this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can resolve it from another side.

I assume the account you're expecting is named 'custom', then override the default yaml with the custom yaml.

```
$ kubectl edit serviceaccount default -n namespace
```

then paste content of 'custom'.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to mess with the default serviceaccount.